# writing numbers to file - strange result

Tags: c++, ofstream

running the following code:

```
ofstream newfile(path + "file" + ".hash", fstream::out);
filefl.open(path + "file" + ".hash", fstream::out);
char  a = 10;
filefl<<a;
filefl.close();
```

results a file with `0D 0A` in it (viewed with hex editor). 
when `a=9` the file that contains `09`. 
`sizeof(char)` is 1. 
my OS is a win7 x64 and the code is run via vs2010 pro. 
can someone explain this?

Comment: What results do you actually expect?  `0D` `0A` is a carriage-return, line-feed.  It's possible that your OS is expanding your 10 (which is 0A) into a CRLF combination.  You should open your file in whatever BINARY MODE is available to you.

Comment: The value `10` is converted by the streams to a carraige return / line feed combination. This is Windows specific btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the stream object is automatically expanding the LineFeed (0xA, or 10) into a Windows-friendly CarriageReturn-LineFeed pair (0xD 0xA).

Comment: If you don't want this behaviour, open the file for reading and writing in binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. You are opening your file in text mode. Windows translates `'\n'` (0x0A) to 0D 0A in text mode. Also be careful not to write 0x1A into such file (it's EOF for text files).

I don't know the purpose of the file, but if it should store binary data, then it should be opened in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are expecting it to print "10", in other words the string '1', '0' to the file.

But a `char` is usually interpreted in C as one character of a string, not a number. The common data type for numbers is the `int`.

So what is happening is that the iostreams functions are defaulting to interpreting your `char` with value 10 as the ASCII character "newline". If you want to actually print 10 then change `char` to `int` or rewrite the output line to use a static cast, like so:

```
filefl << static_cast<int>(a);
```

Comment: I'm not. I'm trying to write `0x0A`

Comment: @elyashiv: A tip then: C programmers do not make a habit of writing characters as numbers. You should use `'\n'` or `'\x0a'` to make it clear you intend it to be a text character.